# StringBuffer within Java constructor?

Tags: java, class, constructor, scope, stringbuffer

When I create a new object with StringBuffer/StringBuilder inside a constructor, it seems I need to create a temporary variable and pass this along to the initialized class variable. That is, when I create a new instance, the changes I make to *sNumber* (example below) in the constructor don't affect the object variable's value -- unless I use a temp variable. For example:

```
public class Some_class {

  public static class algorithm{
    String sNumber = "";

    algorithm(String num){
      String temp = new StringBuilder(num).reverse().toString();
      sNumber = temp;

      //the below expression does not work:
      //sNumber = new StringBuilder(num).reverse().toString();
    }
```

I assumed that since I named the new StringBuilder/StringBuffer object the same name, it would override the value of the previously initialized *sNumber* variable -- but that's not the case. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: The code you've commented out will work absolutely fine. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - I strongly suspect that in trying to do so, you'll find that either it's no longer a problem (e.g. you misdiagnosed it before) or that you find the problem elsewhere.

Comment: Did you by any chance really say `String sNumber = new StringBuilder(num).reverse().toString();`?

Comment: You guys are all correct, particularly @ajb. In my workspace, I wrote `String sNumber = new StringBuilder(num).reverse().toString();` and couldn't figure out why it doesn't work. When I came here, I wrote it the correct way and thought it was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assumed that since I named the new StringBuilder/StringBuffer object the same name, it would override the value of the previously initialized sNumber variable

No, if you name the StringBuilder the same name as the field, it will *hide* the field. (The only way to access the field would then be through `this.sNumber`.)

You can solve it without a temporary variable as follows:

```
sNumber = new StringBuilder(num).reverse().toString();
```

(You say in your question that this does not work, but it should. Just make sure you don't declare `sNumber` as a local variable in the constructor. If it still doesn't work, you need to include the error message in your question.)